# AspNet Core - Settings `NameClaimType` and `RoleClaimType`

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

How do I change the Identity values `NameClaimType` and `RoleClaimType` to "sub" and "role" instead the default SOAP URLs below:

[image: NameClaimType and RoleClaimType]
(More context on the motivation on this github issue: https://github.com/GestionSystemesTelecom/fake-authentication-jwtbearer/issues/4)

Answer (score 5):

1. Configure your identity

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IIdentityUser>(options =>
{ 
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = "sub";
    options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = "role";
})
```

2. Configure your JWT token

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
     .AddJwtBearer(options =>
     {
           options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "sub";
           options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
     });
```

3. Use `await CreateAsync(user)` method on `IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IIdentityUser>` instance. It will create correct `ClaimsIdentity` object with user claims that you can use during JWT token generation.

```
var principal = await _userClaimsPrincipalFactory.CreateAsync(user);
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer, audience, principal.Claims, notBefore, expires, credentials);
```

Comment: Setting options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When constructing the `ClaimsIdentity` class, there's a constructor overload that allows specifiying the claim type for name and role.
See [the official api docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.-ctor?view=netcore-2.2#System_Security_Claims_ClaimsIdentity__ctor_System_String_System_String_System_String_).

Comment: I am using [AddAuthorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvccoremvccorebuilderextensions.addauthorization?view=aspnetcore-2.2) while setting up my services, and there is no option to pass my own `ClaimsIdentity` instance.
Am I looking to configure this in the wrong place?

Comment: The authentication service you've configured is actually responsible for replacing the Identity afaik. Which one are you using? From your GitHub issue, I'd guess you're calling `AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer()`?

Comment: That is Correct.
I looked at `AddJwtBearer` options and also couldn't find anything related to setting a custom `ClaimsIdentity` instance.

Comment: I don't have a setup where I can quickly test this, but does it work if you override the `TokenValidationParameters` `NameClaimType` and `RoleClaimType` in `AddJwtBearer`?

Answer (score 2):

To set custom claim names use code below

```
 services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
 {
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = "value";
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = "value";
    options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = "value";
 });
```

Comment: but i my case this works for all IdentityOptions properties like [User, Password, Lockout] and don't change ClaimsIdentity at all. 
IdentityServer 4 Core 3.0 
Can anybody help?